# Why did G-d promise the former slaves to continue cultivating slavery?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, halacha-theory, slave-serve-eved-avadim, mishpatim

This question is a different aspect of the previous question "[why-parshas-mishpatim-begin-with-laws-of-slaves"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98877/why-does-parshas-mishpatim-begin-with-laws-of-slaves).

A man that is discharged from a prison promises to never get back. A nation that was severely enslaved for hundreds of years, I assume, would want to erase the idea of slavery from its norms, namely a free Jew being a slave of another more powerful and resourceful Jew. I would also presume they would want to eradicate that idea for all nations, being "אור לגויים" - the enlightenment for all nations.

However, the first thing that G-d says to them is that they will continue that practice - selling and buying a needy and starving fellow into human slavery.

It does not sound right to me at all.

Why G-d did not promise the Jews to end slavery once and for all and why did the Jews not revolt against such laws?

Comment: It's quite thoughtful to compare our concept of debt slavery with the one of the gentiles on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt_bondage

Comment: @Kazibácsi It says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debt_bondage#Classical_antiquity it was widespread in Greece and Rome, I couldn't see how different it is from the Torah's concept.

Comment: "where the terms of the repayment are not clearly or reasonably stated, and the person who is holding the debt and thus has some control over the laborer, does not intend to ever admit that the debt has been repaid"

Answer (score 1):

In parshas noach, c'naan is cursed: וַיֹּ֖אמֶר אָר֣וּר כְּנָ֑עַן עֶ֥בֶד עֲבָדִ֖ים יִֽהְיֶ֥ה לְאֶחָֽיו. In a similar way to how Yaakov blessed his sons, Noach was actually directing his children towards the path in life which would yield them the greatest success in this world. He was telling C'naan that as a servant to others he would be able to reach his ultimate shleimus as a human being. Because of who he and the character traits he has, he can do the best for the world by being an eved. See Gur Aryeh, he IS a despised person, in leardership he will not allow society to develop, he will do best for everyone as a slave (including himself because he will not have the freedom to follow his desires to the point of destroying himself). This is the first instance of slavery in the torah (I think) and therefore we learn its essence here. 
Slavery exists in the torah because there are certain people (the torah delineates who) for whom slavery is their best chance of a successful life. And sometimes people are able to recognise this themselves and give themselves up for slavery.
We have laws about how we treat a slave becuase he is a human, a human who has a different path towards a successful life.
We, all of us, are slaves to Hashem. The slavery in Mitzrayim existed to teach us what it is to be a slave, how all encompassing and life consuming slavery is so that we could be ideal servants of Hashem.
We never want to forget what slavery is, we never want to forget that we were slaves  (and Hashem took us out) because that experience of slavery informs out lives to this day.
And we also recognise that just as our slavery enables us to reach our fullest potential, so too, in certain situations for certain people, slavery is very much in place to help them realise their greatest potential.

Answer (score -3):

The Torah allowed the concept of slavery but restricted its practices with the intention of teaching the wrongs within the system. The goal of the Torah was to end slavery. Other examples are the sacrifices, polygamy, and much more. Yet it allows the license to these primitive laws because the ancient Israelites lived in a time where slavery was customary.

The Rambam teaches that although G-d can change human nature, He choices not to do so. Thus G-d has to allow certain rules in the Torah that seem harsh even today. The legislation of slavery, sacrifices, and capital punishment served a better interest for the public, even though a careful reading and analysis will show that the Torah never condoned these practices. For example, the Torah’s legislation of a slave’s life made his life much easier than his contemporaries in other countries. So much so, that the rabbis later said, “he who acquires a slave secures a master over himself,” for in Hebrew the correct translation is “servant.”

Similarly, the sacrificial system was restricted and minimizing only to certain animals and the abhorrence of capital punishment made its infliction impossible. The same can be applied to stoning misbehaving children in Deuteronomy 21:18-21, not offering peace to the Canaanites in Deuteronomy 20:16-18, the laws of a condemned city in Deuteronomy 13:13-19, and the law of a captive woman and Deuteronomy 21:10-14.

For example, the law for an “eye for an eye” was always met with compensation as restricted in the Torah and Oral law in the Talmud(s). The injury was not met with physical damage in any way. The anti-Semites that use this phrase, like slavery and many others, to justify revenge which is forbidden in (Leviticus19:18) shows that these laws were never implemented.

Sources: The parashah found in Exodus 21:19 and Targum Onkelos understands that and eye for an eye is met with payment. See also Midrash Mekhilta and the Babylonian Talmud, Bava Kamma 85a. See Talmud (ibid.). Also Shakespeare’s The Merchant of Venice (4:1) makes is abundantly clear that the law is not physical damage.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and welcome. What I learned on this site (the hard way) is to source my answers. So either find sources that support your reasoning or add IMHO, so it'll be clear that this your personal opinion.

Comment: Your main part *"The goal of the Torah was to end slavery. "* seems to contradict the explicit verse "לעולם בהם תעבדו". Not only that, the Torah obligates us to wage wars on surrounding nations and [either eliminate them completely] or enslave them. This is also true about the Optional Wars when we simply can't leave other nations unaffected. Where does the idea "to end slavery" come from?

Comment: Shalom @AlBerko. A careful reading of the Torah will show that the Torah never condones slavery or the eradication of woman and children of Amalek, the Canaanites, the seven nations, etc.

Comment: You're saying I'm not reading the Torah carefully enough? Please elaborate on how one reads the Torah *carefully*. Also please address the facts I provided.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that you're not reading the Torah correctly, only that a careful reading will show that the Torah does not condone slavery.

Comment: @AlBerko also think of slavery in ancient Israel as indentured servants. The evil institution of slavery in the US was quite different. Master scould not flog, beat, or rape their slaves "servants" in ancient Judaea.

Comment: The Torah often adopts seemingly primitive laws that are to be either improved or eradicated altogether in an attempt to break from pagan rituals. Historians know this process as "synchronization."

Comment: This sounds very heretic. "Poor G-d, the Creation went out of order and He needed to rewrite the Torah to adopt pagan tradition". You keep neglecting my questions. Please explain why the Torah commands on enslaving the surrounding nations?

Comment: @AlBerko G-d created the world as the Bible says "very good." G-d already knew in advance what would be suitable for life. The Rambam writes that G-d can change human nature but choices not to. If He did, free will would be compromised. So G-d allowed the laws pertaining to slavery. But slavery is an evil act. The Jews were once slaves and knew nothing of freedom for 400 years.

Comment: They were enslaved and uneducated. Moshe, on the other, had was a prince, a general, considered the son of the pharaoh. He would have been educated in the laws of the Torah. Since Moshe cannot change human nature and G-d chose not to do the same, the Torah allows harsh pagan laws but remedies them. The Torah does not want us to keep slaves.

Comment: It, therefore, sympathetically grants the lives of slaves better than their contemporaries. The masters had to show them proper treatment and free them after many years of servitude. But the Torah knew these seemingly barbaric laws would be accommodated by other methods.

Comment: I have demonstrated that the laws pertaining to an eye for an eye and the condemning of the inhabitants of a city were never implemented as the Talmud describes. And the laws of the captive women made it nearly impossible to rape her. These are the good morality of the Torah.

Comment: I'm on probation here so I'm limited in my ability to express myself. I'm glad you have a firm outlook on those problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98666/discussion-between-al-berko-and-jonathan).